# How to get WPF Application object from another class library?

Tags: reflection

I have a class library, let's call it `Restarter`. Now I want to call a method `Restart()` from an WPF Application.

Here some code placed in `Restarter` for better understanding

```
    public void Restart()
    {
        System.Windows.Application app = GetApplicationFromCaller();
        ...
    }
```

The Code from my WPF App

```
    public void Foo()
    {
        var restarter = new Restarter();
        restarter.Restart();
    }
```

Is it possible to get the `Application` from the calling method `Foo`?
 I guess if at all, only through reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Current` will give you current application. However, ideally when you design a class library it must be agnostic of whether you call it from WPF app or any other type of application.